# Analytically isomorphic singular points of plane curves have the same multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am new to algebraic geometry and reading the first chapter of Hartshorne. My question is regarding exercise 5. 14 (a) of the book. It says let $P\in X$ and $Q \in Y$ be two analytically isomorphic singular points of two plane curves $X$ and $Y$. Then show that $\mu_p(X) = \mu_Q(Y)$.

Here is my try:

By some change of variable we can assume $P= Q = (0,0)$. Let $L$ be a line which is not tangent to $X $ and $Y $. Then
$\mu_p(X) = ( L. X )_P$ and $\mu_p(Y ) = ( L.Y )_Q $.
Now the intersection multiplicity $( L. X )_P$ is defined as length of $\mathcal{O}_p $ module $\mathcal{O}_p/ (f,s)$ where $ X =z(f) $ and $ L = z(s) $.
Similarly, $( L. Y )_Q$
is defined by length of $\mathcal{O}_p $ module $\mathcal{O}_p/ (g,s)$ where $ Y =z(g) $ and $ L = z(s) $.

Now, how to show that these two lengths will be same using completion of local rings of $X$ and $Y $ at $P $ and $Q $ are isomorphic as $ k$ algebras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by assuming $P$ is the origin by a change of variables. Now we develop an alternate characterization of multiplicity: for $n\leq \mu_P(Y)$, we have $(k[x,y]/(f))/(x,y)^n = k[x,y]/(x,y)^n$, as $f\in(x,y)^n$, and therefore $\dim (k[x,y]/(f))/(x,y)^n=\binom{n+1}{2}$. For $n=\mu_P(Y)+1$, we have $\dim (k[x,y]/(f))/(x,y)^n=\binom{n+1}{2}-1$, so $\mu_P(Y)$ is one less than the first $n$ so that $\dim (k[x,y]/(f))/(x,y)^n < \binom{n+1}{2}$.

Now we use a nice property of completions: if $R$ is a ring with ideal $I$,  then letting $\widehat{R}$ be the completion of $R$ with respect to $I$, we have $\widehat{R}/I^n\cong R/I^n$.
In particular, for any $n$, we have that $$(k[[x,y]]/(f))/(x,y)^n\cong (k[[x,y]]/(g))/(x,y)^n$$ where $f$ and $g$ are the polynomials cutting out $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.
So the above characterization of multiplicity in terms of dimensions of quotients applies here and we're done.

Comment: Why you are considering the quotient by $(x,y)^n$?

Comment: To use the nice property of completions - to get the completed local ring, we complete with respect to $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing for the particular value of $\mu_P(X)+1$ why the dimension is decreased by 1?

Comment: Because that's the first time $f$ isn't in $(x,y)^n$. The ideal generated by $f$ in the ring $k[x,y]/(x,y)^n$ is just one-dimensional, equal to the span of $f\bmod (x,y)^n$. Try it yourself with an example, like $f=x^2+y^2+y^3$.